# Add lines separating totals on pander

Tags: r, formatting, r-markdown, pandoc, pander

Given the following example

```
library(pander)
table <- Titanic[1, 1, , ]
tableWithMargins <- addmargins(table)
pander(tableWithMargins)

----------------------------
  &nbsp;     No   Yes   Sum 
----------- ---- ----- -----
 **Child**   0     5     5  

 **Adult**  118   57    175 

  **Sum**   118   62    180 
----------------------------
```

I would like to add lines separating my column totals, so the pandoc output would be this:

```
----------------------------
  &nbsp;     No   Yes   Sum 
----------- ---- ----- -----
 **Child**   0     5     5  

 **Adult**  118   57    175 
----------------------------
  **Sum**   118   62    180 
----------------------------
```

How can I do this? I've read `?panderOptions` and `?pandoc.table`, but the only thing I found was the `table.style`/`style` parameter, but setting that to simple, multiline, grid or rmarkdown do different things.

Comment: this would exclude the last line from your table once you compile with pandoc...

Comment: Your desired table format is not valid in [pandoc's markdown](http://pandoc.org/README.html#tables). What is your preferred output file? If HTML, you can do this with CSS/JS.

Comment: @daroczig, I'm creating a PDF report. So I'll probably need to use `xtable` instead of `pander`, or can you think of something else?

Comment: @WaldirLeoncio if that's your only required output format, then it's better to stick to LaTeX for sure -- with much more options to fine-tune your document compared to what markdown can offer.